# Excel VBA - Copy comma seperated sentence from emails to seperate Excel cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to include a line in an Excel VBA script which identified all the text in a sentence that appears after the occurance of "Keyword:" in the body of multiple emails and copies each comma separated word into separate Excel cells. The phrases could be anything, always a single word but can't be predefined. For example, the email contained a line like:

```
Keyword: phrase1, phrase2, phrase3, phrase4
```

The result, in Excel:

```
First email: A1 phrase1 B1 phrase2 etc.    
Second email: A2 phrase1 B2 phrase2 etc.
```

I've tried to use something like the following but don't know where to go from there:

```
CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp").Pattern = "((Keyword:)\s*(\w*),\s*(\w*),\s*(\w*),\s*(\w*),\s*(\w*))"
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Count_Emails()

Dim oNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oTaskFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim oFoldToSearch As Object
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim dStartDate, dEnddate As Date

Set oWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set oNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oTaskFolder = oNS.Folders("bill.gates@microsoft.com")
Set oFoldToSearch = oTaskFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("New Folder")
Set oItems = oFoldToSearch.Items

intCounter = 1
dStartDate = oWS.Range("A1").Value
dEnddate = oWS.Range("B1").Value

Do

With oWS
    If DateSerial(Year(oItems(intCounter).ReceivedTime), Month(oItems(intCounter).ReceivedTime), Day(oItems(intCounter).ReceivedTime)) >= dStartDate And _
       DateSerial(Year(oItems(intCounter).ReceivedTime), Month(oItems(intCounter).ReceivedTime), Day(oItems(intCounter).ReceivedTime)) <= dEnddate And _
       oItems(intCounter).Subject Like "*Keyword:*" Then
       'Something needs to happen here? A VBScript.RegExp.Pattern maybe?         
    End If
End With

intCounter = intCounter + 1

Loop Until intCounter >= oItems.Count + 1

Set oNS = Nothing
Set oTaskFolder = Nothing
Set oItems = Nothing

End Sub
```

EDIT: To clarify that the phrases are not pre-defined, they could be anything.

EDIT2: To clarify that the body of the emails contains "Keyword:" followed by comma separated single words that are to be copied each into their own Excel cell.

Comment: I think you're looking for oItems.body.  Declare a variable as variant and make it equal to the message body.  Then you can scan through it with instr to find the keywords you're looking for, and pluck out the delimited strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here I iterate over an array of phrases using instr to find the position of the phase in the mail item's subject.  If the position in greater then 0 I use it to calculate the potion of the subject to write to the worksheet.

---

Count_Emails uses a ParamArray to accept up to 29 arguments in VBA 2003 or earlier and up to 60 arguments in VBA 2007 or later.

For Example if you only wanted to search for a single phrase:

NumberOfEmails = Count_Emails( "Phrase1" )

On the other hand if your had three phrases you need to search for, just add them as additional arguments

NumberOfEmails = Count_Emails( "Phrase1", "Phrase2", "Phrase3" )

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function Count_Emails(ParamArray Phrases())
    Dim Count as Long
    Dim oNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim oTaskFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim phrase As Variant
    Dim item As Object, oFoldToSearch As Object
    Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date, MailDate As Date
    Dim PhraseSize As Long, pos As Long

    Set oNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oTaskFolder = oNS.Folders("bill.gates@microsoft.com")
    Set oFoldToSearch = oTaskFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("New Folder")
    Set oItems = oFoldToSearch.Items

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        StartDate = .Range("A1").Value
        EndDate = .Range("B1").Value

        For Each item In oItems

            MailDate = DateValue(item.ReceivedTime)
            If MailDate >= StartDate And MailDate <= EndDate Then
                For Each phrase In Phrases
                    pos = InStr(item.Subject, phrase)
                    If pos > 0 Then
                        With .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                            PhraseSize = Len(phrase)
                            .Value = Right(item.Subject, Len(item.Subject) - pos - PhraseSize + 1)

                        End With
                        Count = Count + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next
            End If

        Next

    End With


    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oTaskFolder = Nothing
    Set oItems = Nothing
    Count_Emails = Count 
End Function
```

Comment: "_...The phrases could be anything, always a single word but can't be predefined..._"

Comment: @xmojmr I updated my answer.  Do you see anything else that I missed?

Comment: can you show how to build the `Phrases` array automatically from the "_...in a sentence that appears after a keyword...each comma separated word..._"?

Comment: @xmojmr I updated my answer,  Hopefully, I clarified how to use the function.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thomas Inzina wasn't wrong. I edited the OP to clarify that the phrase could be anything after they posted. 
Thanks, I'll look at this.

Comment: I don't understand how you're building the array here without pre-defining the entries. There are too many possible words for me to pre-define an array which is why I hope to capture comma separated words that appear after the occurrence of "Keyword:" in the body of the email.

Comment: You can easily modify the code to take any array.  How are you storing the keywords?  Are they in a range?

Comment: `ParamArray` is a special type of argument. A ParamArray allows you to pass a variable number of arguments into a sub or function,  You can pass  from 1 to 60 arguments this way.

Comment: I am not storing the keywords anywhere, there are no keywords defined. The goal of the script is to capture comma separated words from a sentence in the body of incoming emails and write them to separate excel cells.

Comment: So you are literally looking for "Keyword:" in the subject line and you want to write the comma separated values after it to a range.

Comment: Yes, only in the body. So, for example, I might receive an email that has, in the body, the text "Keyword: bread, airplane, monkey, window" and I want the script to write to Excel, A1 bread, A2 airplane, A3 monkey, A4 window. The second email writes B1 onwards and etc. I have no way of knowing what the words after "Keyword:" will be in advance, I only know that they will be single words separated by commas, probably no more than 10 words per email.

Comment: I'll post a macro in another answer that you can pass the message body to and it will add a new column each time Keyword: is found.

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly get your aim (see comments) you could modify your code as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Count_Emails()
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oTaskFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim keyword As Variant
    Dim item As Object, oFoldToSearch As Object
    Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date, MailDate As Date
    Dim pos As Long

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application '<--| early binding ==> add your project the reference to Microsoft Excel XX.Y Object library
    Dim phrasesArr As Variant

    Set oNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oTaskFolder = oNS.Folders("bill.gates@microsoft.com")
    Set oFoldToSearch = oTaskFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("New Folder")
    Set oItems = oFoldToSearch.Items


    Set xlApp = GetExcel(True) '<--| get running instance of excel application
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Excel running instance", vbCritical + vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With xlApp.Sheets("Sheet1") '<--| this assumes that the running instance of excel has an open workbook with a sheet named "Sheet1"
        StartDate = .Range("A1").Value
        EndDate = .Range("B1").Value

        For Each item In oItems
            MailDate = DateValue(item.ReceivedTime)
            If MailDate >= StartDate And MailDate <= EndDate Then
                    pos = InStr(item.Subject, "Keyword:") '<--| search for "Keyword:" in current mail subject
                    If pos > 0 Then '<--| if found...
                        phrasesArr = Split(Right(item.Subject, Leng(item.Subject) - pos - Len("keyword:")), ",") '<-- fill an array with "phrases" separated by commas after "keyword:"
                        .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, UBound(phrasesArr) + 1).Value = phrasesArr '<--| write "phrases" in column "C" first non empty cell and its adjacent cells
                    End If

            End If
        Next
    End With

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set oItems = Nothing
    Set oFoldToSearch = Nothing
    Set oTaskFolder = Nothing
    Set oNS = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetExcel(Optional mustBeCurrent As Variant) As Excel.Application
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application

    If IsMissing(mustBeCurrent) Then mustBeCurrent = False '<--| default is get an Excel object "at any cost", if it's not running then create it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") '<--| try getting a running Excel application
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetExcel Is Nothing Then If Not mustBeCurrent Then Set GetExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") '<--| if no running instance of Excel has been found then open a new one
End Function
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that you're defining an Array when that's not something I can do. There are too many possible words for me to pre-define an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ExtractKeyWords(text As String)
    Dim loc As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim KeyWords
    Dim Target As Range

    loc = InStr(text, "Keyword:")

    If loc > 0 Then
        s = Trim(Right(text, Len(text) - loc - Len("Keyword:") + 1))
        KeyWords = Split(s, ",")

        With Worksheets("Sheet1")

            If .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) = "" Then
                Set Target = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
            Else
                Set Target = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            End If

            Target.Resize(UBound(KeyWords) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(KeyWords)

        End With

    End If
End Sub
```